# Android studio has error "Project already exists"

Tags: android

I'm trying to import a ZIP file into my Android Studio, but it always comes up with this error:

[image: Cannot Import Project: The project file specified already exists.]

For your information, the ZIP file when converted into APK is the Rosemary font from Samsung FlipFont modded to insert custom fonts into One UI 2. I don't have any APK file for this, and only a ZIP file. How can I fix this? Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the project folder location and tried re-importing??